# Determine what all is present on a linux server (programs and applications)?

Tags: configuration, redhat

How can I check what software is present on a linux server? This is a default configuration and I want to check if it has apache, php, mysql on it.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the distribution.

For Red Hat, derivatives and other RPM-based distro's, you can type:

```
rpm -qa
```

For Debian and derivatives, you can type:

```
dpkg -l
```

Both will show a list of all installed packages on the machine.

Specifically for you requirements, I'd do the appropriate one and grep -i on httpd (Red Hat) or apache (Debian et al.), php and mysql.

Comment: If you know the specific package name `rpm -q httpd` is faster because the search is narrowed.  But `rpm -qa` will give you a little more flexibility if you don't specifically know the package name.

Comment: rpm -qa showed me lots of information, but didnt mention php or apache, whereas php is definitely installed (I was able to run it from the command prompt)

Comment: On RHEL, the Apache package is called httpd. The OUtput of rpm -qa should mention php.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you'd like to know which software was installed lately. If so, then run `rpm -qa --last | tac`. This shows all installed packages in chronological order.

Answer (score 1):

For redhat/centos/fedora rpm -qa might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GUI installed on a Debian box, you can use synaptic. There is a preconfigured filter to show all installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

there is one more way at /root/install.log will have all rpm install in redhat and centos /fedora server

Answer (score 0):

For Red Hat-derived distributions: `rpm -q httpd php mysql` 
What distro are you running?